# Webview for display video can't load when orientation change

Tags: android, android-webview

The error is shown as :

```
02-09 11:09:43.848: W/PhoneWindow(13886)
```

Previously focused `view` reported `id 2131230940` during `save`, but can't be found during `restore`.

Comment: webview is inside tabview inside fragment not in activity

Answer (score 0):

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
```

If you did not add that one in your activity in AndroidManifest, then your activity recreated on orientation change. If you want your webview not to recreate each time orientation changes, then add that one. Thats the only way i found so far but i guess there's another workaround for that.